# View projects code history/revision/changes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, vs-community-edition

Is there a settings in `VB.NET` where I can find the code history or code revision or code changes of my project like in `netbeans`?

According to my research [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269218(v=vs.120).aspx) it is only available in ultimate edition version.

Is there some sort of plugins that I can download or anything that I can do?

Comment: Are you asking about version control?

Comment: What you're talking about is source code control, which is not a VS function.  The page you linked to says you need VS Ultimate for CodeLens, but that's still not going to help on its own.  CodeLens can find code changes but you need Team Foundation Server to actually record those changes to find.  TFS is Microsoft's source control solution but there are numerous others too, some of which are free and most of which will integrate into VS.

Comment: THank you so much!